# Invalid characters seen while reading from a CSV file in Python 3.10

Tags: python, csv

I am reading some URLs from a CSV file and just printing them in the console. When I print I see for some urls the `'-'` is being replaced by `'â€“'` in the console.

My Function to read csv is below :

```
def read_dict_csv():
    list_of_urls = []
    try:
        with open('csv/result.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
            csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
            #next(csv_reader)
            for line in csv_reader:
                #print(line[0])
                list_of_urls.append(line[0])
    except FileNotFoundError as exp:
        print(exp.strerror, exp.filename)
    return list_of_urls
```

And my CSV file is as below:

```
https://cab.rbi.org.in/[enter image description here][1]docs/Training Cards/Eight Things About Agriculture Commodity Futures You May Want to Know.pdf
https://cab.rbi.org.in/docs/Training Cards/Exposure Norms for UCBs – Important RBI Guidelines.pdf
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a issue with encoding.
What worked for me is passing the encoding attribute on `open` so your code will be:

```
with open('csv/result.csv', 'r', encoding='utf8') as csv_file:
```